# Can ID column be displayed when configuring a list form header using JSON?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, list-form, json-formatting

I would like to display the ID of a list item on a JSON-formatted form.  I tried adding "ID" directly but it would not render.  I created a calculated column that is the concatenation of ID and Title.  This field renders fine in the BODY but not in the HEADER.

**How can the ID of a list item be displayed in it's JSON formatted header?**

Or, is there some workaround/hack that can achieve this same functionality?

Comment: This is a bug with form formatting. The ID value should always be available like it is everywhere else in list formatting. For whatever reason, this is not working as expected in Form formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the current design, you can refer only those columns which are shown on list forms in your JSON.

Similar thread: [How to detect Edit vs New when styling custom list forms with JSON?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/292348/how-to-detect-edit-vs-new-when-styling-custom-list-forms-with-json)

As Chris mentioned in his comment, we should be able to use the `[$ID]` in form formatting as well like we can use it in column/view formatting.

So, I have created a bug/question on GitHub for the same: [Not able to use [$ID] while configuring a list form using JSON](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/6878)