# Not equal to for: Show or hide columns in a list or library form

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, list-form, json-formatting

I've successfully used non "not equal to" formulas [to conditionally show/hide columns in SharePoint default form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-conditional-show-hide)s.

Does anyone know if it is possible to use a "not equal to" operator? If so, what do I use?

The following did not work for me: <>.  Full example:

```
=if([$Owner.email] <> '@me', 'true', 'false')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
=if([$Owner.email] != '@me', 'true', 'false')
```

Check all available operators in conditional formula or JSON formatting at: [JSON formatting operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference#operators)

**Documentations**:

1. [Specify conditional formula to show or hide columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-conditional-show-hide#specify-conditional-formula-to-show-or-hide-columns)

---

**Update from comments**:

You can only use the columns which are visible in list form in conditional formula and form JSON formatting. So, you cannot use Author (Created by) or Modified by column value in formula. This is a known limitation in SharePoint.

More information at: [Can ID column be displayed when configuring a list form header using JSON?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/292429/can-id-column-be-displayed-when-configuring-a-list-form-header-using-json)

Comment: Thanks for the reponse, but no luck.  I tried =if([$Author.email] != '@me', 'true', 'false') and it did not error out - the formula was accepted - but it did NOT work.  NOTE:  I changed Owner to Author.email (for item Created by).

Comment: Unfortunately, you can only use the columns which are visible in list form. So, you cannot use Author (Created by) column value in formula. This is a known limitation in SharePoint.

Comment: Oh! <facepalm>  A thousand thank yous. For those finding their way here from the web, the takeaway is:

-To use NOT in conditional formulas for show/hide, use:  !=
-Limitation:  You cannot use with non-visible P&G columns like Created by and Modified by.  Custom site or list columns are fine and work as outlined by Ganesh Sanap and user79408.  Marking both as answers.

Comment: Does anyone know if `AND()`, `OR()` and `NOT()` statements are supported when trying to show or hide fields?  I have a question specifically about that here which I am trying to answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75167548/what-operators-and-statements-are-supported-in-microsoft-list-conditional-formul

Comment: I have answered your question on stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `!=` instead of `<>`

[Formatting syntax reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference#expressions)

Comment: Thanks for the reponse, but no luck.  I tried =if([$Author.email] != '@me', 'true', 'false') and it did not error out - the formula was accepted - but it did NOT work.  NOTE:  I changed Owner to Author.email (for item Created by).

Comment: Oh! <facepalm>  A thousand thank yous. For those finding their way here from the web, the takeaway is:

-To use NOT in conditional formulas for show/hide, use:  !=
-Limitation:  You cannot use with non-visible P&G columns like Created by and Modified by.  Custom site or list columns are fine and work as outlined by Ganesh Sanap and user79408.  Marking both as answers.