# Hide property in Edit Form (JSON customizing)

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, form-formatting

I am using Document Sets in SharePoint Online. Some of the properties are  calculated by a workflow and therefore I want to hide/disable them on the edit form. But they should be shown on the view form. Hiding the property hides it in the edit form but also in the view form.

Same result if I use `"SetShowInEditForm=$True"` via PnP.

Is there any possibility to use an expression in the JSON formatting to detect the edit form?

Comment: Check [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/292429/can-id-column-be-displayed-when-configuring-a-list-form-header-using-json) and [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/292348/how-to-detect-edit-vs-new-when-styling-custom-list-forms-with-json). Let me know if it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

As per the current design, you can refer only those columns which are shown on list forms in your JSON.

Using Created, ID, or Author in JSON code will not work as those fields are not shown on list forms.

So, I don't think there is any way to check if the current list form is New form or Edit form using JSON.

Check answers on below threads for more information:

1. [Can ID column be displayed when configuring a list form header using JSON?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/292429/can-id-column-be-displayed-when-configuring-a-list-form-header-using-json)
2. [How to detect Edit vs New when styling custom list forms with JSON?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/292348/how-to-detect-edit-vs-new-when-styling-custom-list-forms-with-json)